# The fastest way to copy a 32bits array into 16bits arrays?

Tags: c, memcpy

What is the best way to copy a 32bits array into 16bits arrays?

I know that "memcpy" uses hardware instruction.But is there a standard function to copy arrays with "changing size" in each element?

I use gcc for armv7 (cortex A8).

```
uint32_t tab32[500];
uint16_t tab16[500];
for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
    tab16[i]=tab32[i];
```

Comment: You're going to need a ton of KY to fit a 32-bit integer into a 16-bit slot (are you sure you don't want to do it the other way around?)

Comment: why `tab16[i]=tab32[i];` ? what exactly ***is *** `tab32[i]`. Do the 32 bit array contains 16 bits unsigned int at each position?

Comment: i want to copy all lower 16 bits(some elements are signed and some unsigned): -1 go to -1, -32000 go to -32000, 65000 go to 65000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ARM cortex A8 with Neon instruction set, the fastest methods use interleaved read/write instructions:

```
vld2.16 {d0,d1}, [r0]!
vst1.16 {d0}, [r1]!
```

or saturating instructions to convert a vector of 32-bit integers to a vector of 16-bit integers.

Both of these methods are available in c using gcc intrinsic. It's also possible that gcc can autovectorize a carefully written c-code to use nothing but these particular instructions. This would basically require that there's a one to one correspondence with all the side effects of these instructions and the c code.

Comment: I'd instruct to use `gcc -S -O2` (and to check the syntax of the autovectorize optimization flags). Then basically the compiler should be able to produce at least as good code as above and probably even better. Then ask your self: are there extra load / store or arithmetic instructions? Are there extra instructions to count the number of iterations? Or to combat misaligned data? Most of these constraints can be hinted to the compiler: `output[0] = (uint32_t)data[0] & 0x0000ffff;`. `for (i = 0; i < 48 * 8; i+=8) { // manually unroll by 8 }`; align the input data by at least 64 bits etc.

Comment: i doesn't have any more instructions in the loop or in the "control block 'for'": (;test;instruction). Thanks, i hope my (lminaro)gcc 4.7.2 optimise it quite good (-O2).

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard function that does this, mostly because it would be very specific to your application.

If you know that the integers in `tab32` will be small enough to fit in a uint16_t, the code in your question is probably the best you can get (the compiler will do the rest if it can optimize something).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't need to modify the data you can use a pointer to  uint16_t on the 32 bits array. It assume that the bare memory make sense as an array of 16 bits unsigned int.

edit: on hold, something is not clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using memcpy will be the fastest way in my opinion. memcpy's are optimized separately for each architecture so you should be good.

On the other hand, since registers are 32bit in ARM, and 16bit values are zero/sign extended to 32bit in the back end anyway. So, I think, it would be more efficient to leave them as 32bit arrays and not copy the data into 16bit arrays (You should actually measure to make the correct decision).

There is one method which can save you size and improve performance (hopefully) If you store the incoming value in an int-array but each int would have two of 16bit values.

```
For example: int[4] would look like this:
----------------------------------------------------------------
|      32bit   ||      32bit   ||      32bit   ||      32bit   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 16bit | 16bit|| 16bit | 16bit|| 16bit | 16bit|| 16bit | 16bit|
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There will be a little preprocessing required(like reading the values as char(bytes) and then, (char*) typecasting on the int-array to store two values in one slot.

The last approach is not guaranteed to give you better performance unless all your algorithm (which you are going to apply on the array) work seamlessly with this layout of elements. Maybe you have to modify the algorithms a little bit to work with this data-structure. For e.g. some bit manipulation algorithms (and, or etc) can be applied to this data-structure without so much work.